# How to query ARCGIS REST Service via ajax with street address

Tags: ajax, rest, esri

Not very familiar with the necessary GIS concepts so this is a beginner question. From my web app I am querying a GIS REST Service using this query:

> require([
>      "dojo/dom", "dojo/on",
>      "esri/tasks/query", "esri/tasks/QueryTask", "dojo/domReady!"
>           ], function (dom, on, Query, QueryTask) {

```
        var queryTask = new QueryTask("http://gis.something.org/arcgis/rest/services/XXXX/Operational/MapServer/6"); 
        var query = new Query();
        query.returnGeometry = false;
        query.outFields = [
        "DISTRICTID "
        ];

        query.where = "SUBID = '" + SUBJID + "'";

        queryTask.execute(query, showResults);
```

In this scenario I had a subject ID (SUBID) which I used for the query to return which district the subject falls in (i.e. the respective DistrictID). I now want to query the service by street address, rather than by SUBID. Any pointers how to structure the query in this case?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in query.where, just add ' AND ' or ' OR ' to concatenate the where attribute with other conditions...

example:

```
query.where = "SUBID = '" + SUBJID + "'" + ' AND ' + "otherAttr = " + otherVar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any pointers query in this case

```
 var q = new Query();
        var query = "SUBID = '" + SUBJID + "'";
        query = query + " and " + "attr = " + attrValue
        q.where = query;
```